# Android SQLlite Database query not ordering

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working with sqlite query where I am selecting multiple records from Database Table by passing ids to the db table. Now I want when I select the records they should be ORDERED. But its not ordering, below is my query please tell me where I am doing the wrong.

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_product WHERE productId IN (" + makePlaceholders(ids.length)+")"+ " ORDER BY rating DESC";
```

It only returns the records match with the given ids but they are not in order.

And here is my `makePlaceholders` method

```
public String makePlaceholders(int len){
        if(len > 0){
        StringBuilder nameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            nameBuilder.append("?").append(",");
        }
        nameBuilder.deleteCharAt(nameBuilder.length() - 1);

        return nameBuilder.toString();
        } else{
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: try running `sqlite3` on your device for experimenting with your db, you can post the whole session if you still have problems

Comment: Can you just fetch all "rating" value ? And share the log ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto currently i am sending 8 products ids where rating for most of them is 0.0 and for other 3 and the logcat does not shows up anything.

Comment: What do you mean by log cat does not show anything ? Did you take log for "rating" column value for each row ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto the rating value for each is just 0.0 after put a log on them

Comment: So, Isn't it obvious, the "order by" clause won't work considering "rating" column's values as all rows have same value for rating column i.e. 0.0 ?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto are you there?